# Ruby SDK from Amadeus Flight: Migration from Low-fare Search to Flight Offers Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sdk, endpoint, amadeus

I am having trouble with the migration of the Ruby SDK from Amadeus Flight Low-fare Search to Flight Offers Search

I'm currently using the Ruby SDK for my student project , and just got the notification about the migration of Amadeus Flight Low-fare Search to Flight Offers Search.

It looks like the SDK endpoint `amadeus.shopping.flight_offers.get()` is still going to Low-fare Search instead of Flight Offers.

I tried updating my parameters for the transition to Flight Offers Search as so:

```
response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers.get(
      originLocationCode: origin,
      destinationLocationCode: destination,
      departureDate: departure_date,
      returnDate: return_date,
      adults: 1
    )
```

And received the following error:

```
Amadeus::ClientError ([400]
[origin] This field must be filled.
[destination] This field must be filled.):
```

And while the following request works, this is reaching the Low-fare Search instead of the Flight Offers Search:

```
response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers.get(
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      departureDate: departure_date,
      returnDate: return_date
    )
```

I've noticed that the documentation shows that `amadeus.shopping.flight_offers.get` is the namespaced client for `/v1/shopping/flight-offers`, while it looks like the Flight Offers endpoint is `/v2/shopping/flight-offers`.

Is there a different Ruby SDK endpoint I should be using to access the Flight Offers Search?

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby SDK was not fully updated. I just released a new version 5.0.0 adding the support for Flight Offers Search and Flight Choice Prediction v2 and removed the support of Flight Low-fare Search and Flight Choice Prediction v1.
You need first to update your amadeus library:

```
gem install amadeus
```

You can then use the [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference):

```
amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.get(originLocationCode: 'NYC', destinationLocationCode: 'MAD', departureDate: '2020-10-01', adults: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Anthony! I'm all set now with the updated SDK!